# Showing $\mathbb{Z}_n\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to $D_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is Exercise 3.2.2 of F. M. Goodman's *"Algebra Abstract and Concrete"*.

> Show that $j: [x]\mapsto [-x]$ is an order $2$ automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Conclude that $\alpha: [1]_2\mapsto j$ determines a homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ into $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$. Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_n\rtimes_\alpha \mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to $D_n$.

### My Attempt:

Here $j$ is well-defined and injective because
$$\begin{align}
j ([x])=j ([y])&\Leftrightarrow [-x]=[-y] \\
&\Leftrightarrow -[x]=-[y] \\
&\Leftrightarrow [x]=[y],
\end{align}$$ and is surjective since $[x]=j([-x])$ for each $[x]\in \mathbb{Z}_n$. Hence $j$ is a bijection.

We have, for $[x], [y]\in \mathbb{Z}_n$, that
$$\begin{align}
j ([x]+[y])&=j([x+y]) \\
&=[-(x+y)] \\
&=[-x]+[-y] \\
&=j([x])+j([y]),
\end{align}$$ so $j$ is an automorphism.

Moreover, for $[x]\in \mathbb{Z}_n$,
$$\begin{align}
(j\circ j)([x])&=j(j([x])) \\
&=[-(-x)] \\
&=[x],
\end{align}$$ so $j$ has order $2$.

Clearly $\alpha: [1]_2\mapsto j, [0]_2\mapsto id$ is a homomorphism since
$$\begin{align}
\alpha([x]+[y])&=\alpha([x+y]) \\
&=\begin{cases}
j &:[x]\neq [y] \\
id &:[x]=[y]
\end{cases} \\
&=\alpha([x])\circ\alpha([y]).
\end{align}$$

Now what do I do to prove $\mathbb{Z}_n\rtimes_\alpha \mathbb{Z}_2\cong D_n$?

### Thoughts

I'm stuck.

Please help :)

Comment: This depends on your definition of $D_n$, so you need to tell us that. It is possible to define it as the semidirect product in question, but presumably that is not the definition you are using.

Comment: The definition of $D_n$ is given geometrically ibid. It's the dihedral group of order $2n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a lot on your particular definitions, so I'll sketch the idea informally for you, and leave it up to you to use your setting to make it formal.

Let $n\geq 3$. We see that $\mathbb{Z}_n\leq D_n$ and that there exists a $\mathbb{Z}_2\leq D_n$ that isn't a subgroup of the copy of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.  It follows from the way that the copy of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are situated inside of $D_n$ that $\mathbb{Z}_n\rtimes_\alpha \mathbb{Z}_2\cong G\leq D_n$. Counting the number of elements tells us that $|G|=2n=|D_n|<\aleph_0$ so actually they are isomorphic.

In general, "give an injective homomorphism from $G$ into $H$ and show $|G|=|H|<\aleph_0$" is an excellent way to show that two groups are isomorphic and is an approach that you should make a part of your toolbox. In practice, you rarely need to show it's of equal size (which can actually be hard in some contexts) you just need to show it's bigger than any proper subgroup.